# RowDataBound row highlight

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to highlight rows based on number on column 11th on my data set (image attached).  I expect all rows that have value in 11th column < 5000 will be highlighted red. Below is my code:

```
  Protected Sub loadData()    
        gvRsrvtionValdtn.DataSource = ds
                Dim myTable As System.Data.DataRowCollection
                myTable = ds.Tables(0).Rows
                If myTable.Count > 0 Then
                    For i = 0 To myTable.Count - 1
                        If myTable(i)(10) > 5000 Then
                            alist.Add(i)
                        End If    
                Next
            End If

            gvRsrvtionValdtn.DataBind()
            btnExp.Visible = True
        End Sub
    Protected Sub gvRsrvtionValdtn_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvRsrvtionValdtn.RowDataBound
            Dim myRow As TableRow = e.Row()
            If alist.Contains(e.Row.RowIndex) Then
               myRow.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End Sub



 <asp:GridView ID="gvRsrvtionValdtn" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                BackColor="Black" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                CellPadding="4" CssClass="aspdatagrid" ForeColor="Black" CellSpacing="1"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="fixHdr" Width="98%" EmptyDataText="No records found" 
                EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="emptyData" RowStyle-Wrap="false"
                **OnRowDataBound ="gvRsrvtionValdtn_RowDataBound"**>
```

On debug, I can see records with columns 11th value < 5000 entering `alist`, but were not highlighted on displaying. Please advise.

```
[my data set][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm7n8.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal working example of what you are trying to achieve.
In the below snippet, rows where column 2 is less than 100 gets a different color.

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="HighlightRowsInDGV_Web.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>below this<br />
        <asp:GridView ID="gvRsrvtionValdtn" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
                BackColor="green" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" 
                CellPadding="4" CssClass="aspdatagrid" ForeColor="Black" CellSpacing="1"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="fixHdr" Width="98%" EmptyDataText="No records found" 
                EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="emptyData" RowStyle-Wrap="false"
                OnRowDataBound ="gvRsrvtionValdtn_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public alist As New BindingList(Of entry)
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim oneentry As New entry()
        oneentry.blah = "blah blah blah 1"
        oneentry.bleh = 50

        Dim anotherEntry As New entry()
        anotherEntry.blah = "blah blah blah 2"
        anotherEntry.bleh = 100

        Dim yetagain As New entry()
        yetagain.blah = "blah blah blah 3"
        yetagain.bleh = 25

        alist.Add(oneentry)
        alist.Add(anotherEntry)
        alist.Add(yetagain)
        loadData()
    End Sub


    Protected Sub loadData()
        gvRsrvtionValdtn.DataSource = alist
        gvRsrvtionValdtn.DataBind()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub gvRsrvtionValdtn_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvRsrvtionValdtn.RowDataBound
        Dim ref As Integer = 100
        If e.Row.RowIndex > -1 Then 'if this is not the header row
            If CType(e.Row.Cells(1).Text, Integer) < 100 Then
                e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.AliceBlue
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Class entry
        Public Property blah As String
        Public Property bleh As Integer
    End Class

End Class
```

Here's an updated method following your comment. You questions and problems are a bit unclear. Your opening questions says...

> > if data in column is smaller than 5000, then highlight the row...

That's what the snippet does, although mine does it on 100 rather than 5000...

```
Protected Sub gvRsrvtionValdtn_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvRsrvtionValdtn.RowDataBound
    Dim ref As Integer = 100
    If e.Row.RowIndex > -1 Then 'if this is not the header row
        'If CType(e.Row.Cells(1).Text, Integer) < 100 Then
        '    e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.AliceBlue
        'End If
        If alist.Contains(e.Row.DataItem) And CType(e.Row.DataItem, entry).bleh < 100 Then
            e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.AliceBlue
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Blaze - thanks for your inputs. However, I want to make my code work because I know data (rows) were collected into my alist in gvRsrvtionValdtn_RowDataBound. The matter is how to get them display. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Added a modified method. If you want us to work with your actual code, you need to supply us actual code... If you paste the code you supplied in a brand new project, you'll see what we are missing. Your snippet does not show us what are `alist` and `ds`.

Comment: 474199 | PEDERSL | 4/12/2013 13:19 | 6/1/2013 0:00  | 189  | QC-7/ 6013 Power Plate | 28 | Copper Brass Sales | -1 | Undefined Reporting Flowpath | 15000 | 41300 | Yes | Yes

Comment: Below is one of records in my ds.  My alist basically contains all records with value in in column 11st  greater than 5000.   Record I show you here having value 41300 in column 11st,.                                                             
 474199 | PEDERSL | 4/12/2013 13:19 | 6/1/2013 0:00  | 189  | QC-7/ 6013 Power Plate | 28 | Copper Brass Sales | -1 | Undefined Reporting Flowpath | 15000 | 41300 | Yes | Yes

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to access to row level. After adding this line: For Each cell As TableCell In myRow.Cells inside IF Statement of  Protected Sub gvRsrvtionValdtn_RowDataBound, it works:

```
Protected Sub gvRsrvtionValdtn_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As 
GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Dim myRow As TableRow = e.Row()
    If e.Row.RowIndex > -1 Then
        If alist.Contains(e.Row.RowIndex) Then
            For Each cell As TableCell In myRow.Cells
                cell.BackColor = Color.Red
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```